# Android gradle project - Proguard

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard

I migrated from android eclipse project  to android gradle project and now have issues with proguarding:

> java.io.IOException: Can't write [build\intermediates\classes-proguard\release\classes.jar] (Can't read [\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\unspecified\jars\libs\libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar(;;;;;;!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)] (Duplicate zip entry [com/google/a/a/a/a.class == libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar:com/google/analytics/tracking/android/Tracker.class]))

My app is broken out into different modules.  I have the main android application "app" and its dependencies that are android-libraries.  I am debating whether this was a good approach because of some inter dependencies: app depends on library1 and library2. But library 1 depends on library2 also.  Is this bad?  This isn't a circular dependency I don't think.

Also library1 and app have dependencies on the same external jar that proguard is complaining about, the libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar.  Is this the reason I am getting the error?

Comment: 1. Don't use jars when do not have to:`libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar`, use google play services 2. It looks like you have duplicated classes from dependencies.